# align text to the right in table

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
<div style="width:700px">
<table>
     <tr>
          <td align="right">
               some text here
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I would like the text to be aligned to the right, however it remains aligned to the left. Why?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/WBejT/1/

Comment: @daniel - typo, my bad(fixed now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the width: 700px; inside your table tag. The problem now is that your table isn't just wide enough:
http://jsfiddle.net/qMAT3/

Comment: perfect, I just added `style="width:100%"` to my table tag

Answer (score 2):

Try putting borders on your elements. It will demonstrate why.

```
<div style="width:700px;border:1px solid #000000">
<table border="1">
     <tr>
          <td align="right">
               some text here
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

By default, tables size to their contents, not their wrappers. You need to add `width="100%"` to your table markup.

Comment: yup, this is what i ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="width:700px">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td width="20%" style="text-align:right"> some text here </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```